# Limit the text field characters to 50 - cannot find function slice in Object 0

Tags: javascript

I am using this to limit the characters in the Text Field.

```
textField.value = textField.value.slice(0,50);
textField.value = textField.value.replace(/[^0-9]+/, "");
```

I am getting an error, cannot find function slice in Object 0.

Comment: What is this Textfield? I assume you are talking about html `<textarea>` tag. correct?

Comment: Do you want to limit or truncate? If you want to limit you can also use maxlength.

Comment: Do not keep reading textField.value! Read it once, store it in a variable, manipulate the variable, store the value back into the textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

```
textField.value = textField.value.substr(0,50);
```